# To a path that does not exist, "No source file named..."\Scr/main.c" on TrueSTUDIO

Tags: stm32, stm32cubemx, truestudio

I am studying STM32F407 with CubeMX and TrueSTUDIO. But when i make a project with CubeMX and turn it over to TrueSTUDIO and debug it, gdb refers to the main.c where I made the first project.

> No source file named C:\Users\cloud47\OneDrive - Thinkwaresys Co., Ltd\271\331\305\301 \310\255\270\351\GPIO Test\GPIO Test\Src\main.c.
>
> Temporary breakpoint 2, main () at ..\Src\main.c:81
> 81      HAL_Init();

Deleting and re-creating a project is the same error, even deleting TrueSTUDIO, deleting the registry, and reinstalling it is the same.
I guess it could have been caused by specifying a path to the cloud, since the path that first created the project was a desktop on OneDrive

Comment: Is the file actually there under that path? What about file access permissions?